# Событие onclick на кнопке

Tags: javascript, события

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку, чтобы высвечивался `alert` с текстом кнопки. У меня такой код, это правильно, или надо по-другому прописать?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let btn = document.getElementById('btn-msg');
  btn.onclick = function() {
    alert('Show message');
  }
  btn.onmouseover = function() {
    event.target.style.background = 'red';
  }
  btn.onmouseout = function() {
    event.target.style.background = ''
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btn-msg">Show message</button>
<button id="btn-generate">Generate item</button>
<p><strong id="tag">Tag:</strong></p>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде присутствует ошибка: необходимо указать обработчикам событий аргумент event там, где это необходимо. Помимо этого, рекомендую выводить текст через `this.textContent`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let btn = document.getElementById('btn-msg');
  btn.onclick = function() {
    alert(this.textContent);
  }
  btn.onmouseover = function(event) {
    event.target.style.background = 'red';
  }
  btn.onmouseout = function(event) {
    event.target.style.background = ''
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btn-msg">Show message</button>
<button id="btn-generate">Generate item</button>
<p><strong id="tag">Tag:</strong></p>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, а касательно моего вопроса что-то сказать можете?

Comment: Вывод текста при клике через onclick - вполне адекватное решение, ничего плохого о нём сказать не могу, так что всё правильно. Разве что можно было воспользоваться addEventListener() для навешивания обработчика.

Comment: Хорошо, я просто думал, а можно ли сделать так, чтобы туда мог выводиться любой текст с этой кнопки в случае если мы заменим текст на кнопке, а в функции прописан неправильный.

Comment: this.textContent, который я вам показал выше, решает этот вопрос.

Comment: Точно, спасибо огромное!

Comment: Возможно, вы неплохо разбираетесь в физике и сможете ответить на мой вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/786446/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%85%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b0