# Сопротивление воздуха при движении мяча

Tags: javascript, canvas, физика

Написал свой симулятор мячей на `JavaScript`. Рисую всё в `canvas`. Рассчитываю сопротивление воздуха довольно примитивным образом: если скорость по оси (`Оx` или `Оy`) положительна, отнимаю от неё определённый коэффициент, иначе его прибавляю. Таким образом, мяч постепенно замедляется, меня это устраивало. Но недавно случайно наткнулся на формулу сопротивления на википедии:
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сила сопротивления направлена против скорости движения, её величина пропорциональна характерной площади `S` (Считаю как `PI*r^2`), плотности среды ρ (Взял плотность воздуха, что в районе `1.2 кг/м^3`) и квадрату скорости `V`.
 `Cx0` — безразмерный аэродинамический коэффициент сопротивления, получается из критериев подобия, например, чисел Рейнольдса и Фруда в аэродинамике. (Я взял из одной статьи значение 0.47)
В итоге, когда я добавил эту формулу в свой код, она не сработала, как я думал. Вот этот код:
`obj` - объект мяча;
`obj.velocity` - Вектор скорости, который добавляется к вектору позиции (`obj.position`) каждую итерацию игрового цикла. Свойство x - скорость по оси `Оx, y` - скорость по оси `Oy` соответственно;
`obj.r` - радиус мяча;

```
if (obj.velocity.x > 0) {
    obj.velocity.x -= 0.47*(1.2041 * obj.velocity.x ** 2) / 2 * obj.r ** 2 * Math.PI;
} 
else {
    obj.velocity.x += 0.47*(1.2041 * obj.velocity.x ** 2) / 2 * obj.r ** 2 * Math.PI;
}
if (obj.velocity.y > 0) {
    obj.velocity.y -= 0.47*(1.2041 * obj.velocity.y ** 2) / 2 * obj.r ** 2 * Math.PI;
} 
else {
    obj.velocity.y += 0.47*(1.2041 * obj.velocity.y ** 2) / 2 * obj.r ** 2 * Math.PI;
}
```

Данный код выполняется каждую итерацию игрового цикла, изменение скорости происходит перед добавлением скорости к вектору позиции. Но вместо замедления мячей они невероятно ускоряются, их скорость превращается в `NaN`. Думаю, что-то не так с формулами, но как решить, не знаю, поэтому обращаюсь к вам. Также хотелось бы узнать про силу трения и как её правильно посчитать, потому что мячи в моей симуляции могут на ней находиться и каких-то расчётов при этом я не провожу.

Comment: Формула же выдает **силу**, а Вы ее пытаетесь прибавить к скорости. Понятно, что получается ерунда.

Comment: Тогда как мне быть, если нужна именно скорость?

Comment: Ну, зная силу и массу, по первому закону Ньютона можно найти ускорение. А зная ускорение и время, без проблем находится дельта скорости.

Comment: У меня ничего не вышло))